# Solving open problems through a misunderstanding

Tags: history

We all know the (apparently verified<sup>1</sup>) anecdote recounting 
[George Dantzig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Dantzig)
arriving late to a lecture (by Jerzy Neyman), and later solving two open
problems written on the board, mistaking them for homework.
My question is:

> ***Q***. Are there other examples of a similar misunderstanding
>   that led to the solution of an unsolved problem?

Perhaps even in an exam, where an exam question's novel solution led to
a new perspective on the topic?
This possibility inspired by [Interesting things you learned while grading?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/18297/511).

---

<sup>1</sup>
Mentioned in [Dantzig's obituaries](https://supernet.isenberg.umass.edu/photos/gdobit.htm).

Comment: There are other versions of your Danzig story, but instead featuring other names.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: I'd be interested to hear of (or a link to) these other stories.

Comment: https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/the-unsolvable-math-problem/

Answer (score 3):

William Tutte apparently introduced the concept of the thickness of a graph. I have a memory of reading or being told that the concept of the coarseness of a graph arose because Paul Erdos misunderstood the definition of thickness.