# How to convince a high school student that the $=$ symbol denotes identity?

Tags: arithmetic-operations, equal-sign

In French language, arithmetic statements are often read, at the elementary school level, as , say, " deux et deux font quatre" , i.e. something like " two and two make four".

Out of this arises a belief according to which the $ \Large= $ symbol expresses some sort of action , either an action performed by numbers themselves or by the person that operates the mental activity of computation which is supposed to be denoted by the $\Large +$ sign.

This first belief may, in the head of older students, be replaced by the idea that $\Large =$ means " has the same magnitude " or " has the same value as".

I tried to show to high school students that the supposedly active meaning of $\Large =$ does not work anymore when the equality is reversed : $2+2$ may ( arguably)  " make" $4$ , but would one say that  $4$ " makes " $2+2$ ?

But I did no manage to convince them that, at least in the case of arithmetic statements, the " has the same magnitude " interpretation is not correct.

The identity meaning seems simply unbelievable  to students.

Comment: As charming as it is, the French language is weird.  One says "Jean has 16 years" to talk about age and "It is doing cold" to talk about weather.  This can't be the first time your students have considered action verbs that are idiomatically used to describe the state of an object.

Comment: In your experience, do English speaking students easily admit that equality is identity?

Comment: I mean , is the problem I point out a well identfied problem in mathematcal teaching elsewhere than in France?

Comment: That said, I appreciate your students' perspective that equality is a relation that describes when two arithmetic expressions have the same magnitude.  $2\times2=3+1$ is a true mathematical statement that doesn't have an interpretation under your sense of identity (at least, if I understand your position correctly).

Comment: Is it really that your students aren't *believing* you when you say what the sign means, or is it that you can't get it to stick in their minds? Because in the latter case, I might try overdoing it with the language: change whatever you usually say in place of the sign (like "equals" in English) by some more verbose and explicit version, like "is the same number as".

Comment: If American teachers do settle this with their students, it is before high school (and you'd need a primary teacher to tell you what that lesson is like).  In the first year of algebra, I build on substitution of equivalent expressions when solving systems of equations.  But they grasp it well with at most a little one-on-one time.

Comment: I have seen this plenty in college students.

Comment: I don't think there's anything peculiarly French about your situation. See https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/issues-with-equals-where-does-this-come-from-and-how-do-i-combat-it . Slightly worse maybe. I wouldnt know...

Comment: Ontology ontologically precedes epistemology. But epistemology psychologically precedes ontology. IOW for young 'uns there is at most the vaguest "is" but a strong sense of "do" backed on an even stronger base of feelings, sensations -- «Why is maman leaving me in the dark??» «I'm hungry!» etc The ultimate business of the math-teacher is not math edu per se but to convey a feel for an outlook independent of changes in space and time... Aka the Platonic world. And the cognition of identity is key to that world. Dunno that there's any short road. It's nevertheless a primary task

Comment: I draw ur attention particularly to [this comment](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/issues-with-equals-where-does-this-come-from-and-how-do-i-combat-it#comment16503_7965)

Comment: In many programming languages, for example those of the C family, the symbol $=$ denotes asignment. The expression $a = b$ is nonsymmetric, as it assigns to the variable $a$ the value of the variable $b$, and this value is the value of the expression. Such languages use $==$ to check equality (so $a == b$ returns a $0$ or $1$). This is just to say that what students assume about $=$ is so natural that it's built into some programming languages. Mathematicians use $=$ in the same way when they use $A = B$ to mean $A$ is defined to equal $B$.

Comment: 1. "*How to convince a high school student that the = symbol denotes identity?*"
$\quad$
The word ‘identity’ has multiple meanings in mathematics and formal logic, and  while your usage is not wrong, it is probably better to call the `=` in $x+2=7$ ‘equality’ and the `=`/`≡` in $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$ and $x^2-y^2≡(x+y)(x-y)$ ‘[identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813)’.

Comment: 2. "*a belief according to which the $ \Large= $ symbol expresses some sort of action performed by the person that operates the mental computation $\Large +$ on the numbers*"
$\quad$
The “action”/operation interpretation of `=` actually has an alternative sense, which turns out to be more correct: instead of the input being its LHS and the output being its RHS, here the inputs are both its LHS and RHS and the output is True/False. This interpretation, aptly, circles back to the ‘equality’ meaning of `=` (above).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although some of the trouble may be language dependent, there is also the issue (here in the U.S., too, in English) that young students get the feeling, perhaps from teachers, even, that = is like saying "and here's what comes next".

I have seen research on this issue. I can't find exactly what I was looking for, but did find [this](https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/commerrs/#Consciousness):

"To put it simply: Some students ... use the equals sign (=) as a symbol for the word "then" or the phrase "the next step is." For instance, when asked to find the third derivative of x4+7x2–5, some students will write "x4+7x2–5 = 4x3+14x = 12x2+14 = 24x." Of course, those four expressions are not actually equal to one another.

"A slight variant of this error consists of connecting several different equations with equal signs, where the intermediate equals signs are intended to convey "equivalent to" --- for example, x = y – 3 = x+3 = y. This is very confusing and altogether wrong, because equality is transitive --- i.e., if a=b and b=c then a=c, but x certainly is not equal to x+3. It would be better to replace that middle equals sign with some other symbol. The most obvious symbol for this purpose is ≡, which means "is equivalent to," but that symbol has the disadvantage of looking too much like an equals sign, and thus possibly leading to the same confusion. Thus, a better choice would be ↔ or ⇔, both of which mean "if and only if." Thus, I would rewrite the example above as x = y – 3 ⇔ x+3 = y."

The author called this 'stream of consciousness' notation.

I have seen both of these issues, and I just keep reminding students that they are writing something incorrect.

Edited to add: Thanks to the comments, [here's a link to a similar question, in which the accepted answer](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/issues-with-equals-where-does-this-come-from-and-how-do-i-combat-it) includes links to research.